# Python: how to print individual dictionary values?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
voorzieningen = {
    "NS-service- en verkooppunt": {"type:": "verkoop- en reisinformatie", "locatie": "spoor 11/12"},
    "Starbucks": {"type": "Winkels en restaurants", "locatie": "spoor 18/19"},
    "Smeulers": {"type": "Winkels en restaurants", "locatie": "spoor 5/6"},
    "Kaartautomaat": {"type": "Verkoop- en reisinformatie", "locatie": "spoor 1"},
    "Toilet": {"type": "Extra voorziening", "locatie": "spoor 4"}
    }


def voorzieningen_op_utrecht():
    for voorziening in voorzieningen:
        print(voorziening)


voorzieningen_op_utrecht()
```

What I want to get is the following:

```
<First value> "is of the type " <second value> "and is located at" <third value>
```

So for example:

***Starbucks is of the type Winkels en restaurants and is located at spoor 18/19.***

I would like it to be a for-loop, so that all values are printed.

P.s. apologies for the Dutch, but that shouldn't make it more difficult to understand the code.

Comment: *"First"*, *"second"* and *"third"* have no meaning, dictionaries don't guarantee order. Have you looked into `str.format`? Also, note that one of your keys is `'type:'` not `'type'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
for key, value in voorzieningen.items():
    print('{} is of the type {} and is located at {}'.format(key, value['type'], value['locatie']))
```

Output for your example

> NS-service- en verkooppunt is of the type verkoop- en reisinformatie and is located at spoor 11/12
>   Kaartautomaat is of the type Verkoop- en reisinformatie and is located at spoor 1
>   Smeulers is of the type Winkels en restaurants and is located at spoor 5/6
>   Starbucks is of the type Winkels en restaurants and is located at spoor 18/19
>   Toilet is of the type Extra voorziening and is located at spoor 4

Answer (score 3):

I would do:

```
template = '{place} is of the type {data[type]} and is located at {data[locatie]}'
for place, data in voorzieningen.items():
    print(template.format(place=place, data=data))
```

This keeps lots of information in the format string, making it easier to verify that you're doing the right thing. However, I get the output:

```
Starbucks is of the type Winkels en restaurants and is located at spoor 18/19
Smeulers is of the type Winkels en restaurants and is located at spoor 5/6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 2, in <module>
    print(template.format(place=place, data=data))
KeyError: 'type'
```

As you have `'type:'` not `'type'` for one of the keys; beware unsanitised input data!

---

### Bonus fact

From Python 3.6, you will be able to use [literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to do this even more neatly, feasibly something like:

```
for place, data in voorzieningen.items():
    print(f'{place} is of the type {data[type]} and is located at {data[locatie]}')
```

Comment: Sharpe by name and action :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in voorzieningen:
  print("%s is of type %s and is located at %s" % (key, voorzieningen[key]['type'], voorzieningen[key]['location']))
```

Comment: C-style `%` string formatting is a little old-fashioned at this point!

Answer (score 1):

```
for k, v in voorzieningen.items():
    print('{} is of the type {} and is located at {}'.format(k, v['type'], v['locatie']))
```

Comment: It's probably neater to move the key into the format string - `'{0} is of the type {1[type]} and is located at {1[locatie]}'`. This makes it easier to be sure that the right thing is in the right place as the string gets longer.